# Visual studio cannot build projects error "The target "ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet" does not exist in the project."

Tags: visual-studio

I was messing around with style cop and scrapped the idea in my project. I deleted the references to style cop and ended up modifying a system file somewhere.

Every project fails to build with the following error:

> The target "ResolveCodeAnalysisRuleSet" does not exist in the project. CDRCallMonitor  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets    39

I scrapped my CSharp.Core.targets file and replaced it with the MS one online
https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#MSBuildFiles/C/ProgramFiles(x86)/MSBuild/14.0/bin_/amd64/Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets

and this doesn't work.

I tried reinstalling msbuild tools and that didn’t help either.

I can't build anything with with msbuild/Visual studio

dotnet build works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you launch the Visual Studio installer there should be an option to uninstall, modify, or **repair**.

Give that repair option a go.